# how to open link when user click on Text ( Click Here To See Full Topic )?

Tags: java, android

I develop (NEWS Android app) with android studio and I have a problem, I Post a Short topic in the app and I need to let the user see the full topic when clicks on TextView (Click Here), but I need to change the site link on every topic. Anyone can help me, please ??

- I Update the news through (Firebase Database and Online Database)

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String url = "https://mobarmejlebanon.000webhostapp.com/show.php";
    TextView textView;
    ListView listview;

    ArrayList<listitme> listitmes = new ArrayList<listitme>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allstudents");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = respons.getString("id");
                                String name = respons.getString("name");
                                String info = respons.getString("info");
                                String img = respons.getString("img");


                                listitmes.add(new listitme(id, name, info, img));
                                listAllItme();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
            }
        }

        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    public void listAllItme() {
        listAdpter lA = new listAdpter(listitmes);
        listview.setAdapter(lA);
    }


    class listAdpter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<listitme> listA = new ArrayList<listitme>();

        public listAdpter(ArrayList<listitme> listA) {
            this.listA = listA;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listA.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listA.get(position).id;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
            TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_info);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);


            id.setText(listA.get(position).id);
            name.setText(listA.get(position).name);
            info.setText(listA.get(position).info);

            Picasso.with(Home.this).load("https://mobarmejlebanon.000webhostapp.com/images/" + listA.get(position).img).into(img);


            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Firebase database code

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Topic2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView TopicTitle,Topic;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mRootReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    DatabaseReference mKidRefernece = firebaseDatabase.getReference("topictwotitle");
    DatabaseReference mChildReference = mRootReference.child("topictwomessage");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic2);

        TopicTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twotitle);
        Topic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twomsg);
        TopicTitle.setText("Please Wait");
        Topic.setText("Loading");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mChildReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Topic.setText(message);


                mKidRefernece.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String topictitle = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        TopicTitle.setText(topictitle);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `CardView` and `RecyclerView` in order to achieve your purpose. You can get a better insight of it [here:](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Also you can catch a glimpse of it in action [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/) and [hither](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtVHvifaKC4).

**EDIT**

According to the new query regarding this question; I think you must catch up this [How to get a text after clicking on the CardView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uBnxSScf_A).

Happy Coding...

Comment: brother i saw the cardview and i think thats what i want , but how to code the links in each topic in Cardview  please ??

Comment: Brother(@Bishoy) please look at the links which I provided below. It explains you exactly what you are looking for

Comment: And do tell brother did it helped?

Comment: :) :) You Are the man broooooo , thats what am looking for .. i will try this now and tell u the result , thanks alot brooooo

Comment: Okay bro; so I am adding this link to the answer and if it worked do mark the answer as accepted  so that it helps me, you and the Stack overflow for the future..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here is your sample:
I added dummy right now.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<TopicDTO> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            topics.add(new TopicDTO("" + i, "Topic " + (i + 1), "Your Topic info goes here", "Your Topic Image goes here", "http://www.google.com"));
        }

        ListView listTopics = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTopics);
        listTopics.setAdapter(new TopicsListAdapter(MainActivity.this, topics));
    }
}
```

TopicsListAdapter.java

```
public class TopicsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<TopicDTO> mData;

    public TopicsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TopicDTO> data) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ChildViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ChildViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_topics, parent,
                    false);
            holder.textTopicTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textTopicTitle);
            holder.textTopicInfo = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textTopicInfo);
            holder.textTopicLink = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textTopicLink);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final TopicDTO mItem = mData.get(position);
        holder.textTopicTitle.setText(mItem.name);
        holder.textTopicInfo.setText(mItem.info);
        /*You need to have a more info link per topic*/
        holder.textTopicLink.setClickable(true);
        holder.textTopicLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='" + mItem.moreInfoLink + "'> Click here to see full topic </a>";
        holder.textTopicLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

        return convertView;
    }

    class ChildViewHolder {
        TextView textTopicTitle, textTopicInfo, textTopicLink;
    }

}
```

row_topics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTopicTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTopicInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!--You need to add extra TextView in your row file of listview.
    It will work as a link per topic.-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTopicLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Click here to see full topic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Read each comment carefully and then implement it. That's it. Nothing can be better than this.

**OLD**

You need to have a textView for each topic you have.You have something like listview or recyclerview. Then when user clicks on that textView open link associated with that topic only that is from your dataset of listview.

Try this on your textview on which you want to open a link :

```
info.setClickable(true);
info.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
info.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Replace "http://www.google.com" with your topic's link.

Comment: brother , i already added Listview in another activity but i don't know how to change links on every topic

Comment: Please post that code. And where is your link for each topic? Post whole code so that it will be more clear to understand.

Comment: Is this helps you?

Comment: thx alot for ur help , i know this solution brother this is for just 1 link but i need to change link in each topic in this listview through firebase or sql database , do u have solution for that brother ?

Comment: It is just simple..Why are you making it so complicated? Let me create an example for you..then I will update my answer.